# C++, Qt - lock guard and the safety of returning an unassignable reference to an object

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, locking

Suppose the following scenario:

I have implemented my own QReadWriteLockGuard:

```
class QReadWriteLockGuard {
public:
    explicit QReadWriteLockGuard(QReadWriteLock & m) : m(m) {m.lockForRead();}
    ~QReadWriteLockGuard() {m.unlock();}

    QReadWriteLockGuard(QReadWriteLockGuard const &) = delete;
    void operator=(QReadWriteLockGuard &) = delete;

private:
    QReadWriteLock & m;
};
```

I have a "manager" object A, which holds an instance of object B.

Object A has a method get_b:

```
const B& A::get_b() const
{
    QReadWriteLockGuard(_b_lock);
    return *_b;
}
```

Now, B of course has its substructure: attributes, public methods etc. Assume that another thread can rewrite the contents of `_b` at any time, or even delete them, if they are pointers. However, it will call `_b_lock.lockForWrite()` first.

Assume that `B` is not assignable (private assignment and copy operators). Is it safe to do this:

`A_instance.get_b().get_vector().at(i).do_stuff()`?

In other words, will the ReadWrite lock be unlocked before or after execution of `do_stuff()`? Or is it perhaps undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `const` reference does not mean that the object is `const`, only that you cannot modify the object via that reference. If one thread has that `const` reference and reads it and another thread writes to the same object (via a non-const reference) then you have a data race.

Your `QReadWriteLockGuard` releases the lock when `A::get_b()` returns, so it won't help.

For this line:

```
A_instance.get_b().get_vector().at(i).do_stuff();
```

Consider that it is more or less equivalent to

```
const B& b = A_instance.get_b();
b.get_vector().at(i).do_stuff();
```

and after the first line you already released the lock.